# postgres select across all schemas

Tags: postgresql

Let say I have 3 schemas: foo, bar, baz. So I could do:

```
select * from foo.table, bar.table, baz.table;
```

What if I don't want to specify schemas names and I would like to select across all schemas or all owned by some user ?

Comment: The query in your example will give a three table unconstrained join. I'm guessing that's not what you want. In any case, the answer is "no" unless you write a function to dynamically create the query for you.

Comment: This time it's exactly what I want - I need it to just list all tables in my devel box to check which contain the data :)

Comment: I find that schemas names can be listed with `select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata;` but I don't know how to build query which will use that.

Comment: plpgsql function. Build SQL from strings. EXECUTE to run the query. It's a UNION ALL you want, not an unconstrained join.

Comment: It's not matter for me if'll get it as multiple outputs for each schema or as one table with additional schema_name field as far as I'll know where the data are. Even `select count(*) from foo.table, bar.table, baz.table;` would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tables have different names (what should be a rule in most cases) set [**search path**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-schemas.html):

```
select * from foo.table1, bar.table2, baz.table3;

set search_path = foo, bar, baz;
select * from table1, table2, table3;
```

Important tip: Use explicit joins instead of listing tables in from clause.

```
select * 
    from table1
    join table2 on ...
    join table3 on ...
```

---

If you have tables with the same name in several schemas you can refer to them in a function. You need information from system catalogs:

- [**pg_class**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-class.html) - catalog containing information about all tables (and other relations) in a database,
- [**pg_namespace**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html) - catalog containing information about all schemas in a database.

This query lists all tables with *given_table_name* in a database:

```
select 
    n.nspname, c.relname
from 
    pg_class c
join 
    pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
where 
    c.relkind = 'r' 
    and c.relname = 'given_table_name';
```

The function below:

- finds all tables with given name in pg_class,
- looks up to pg_namespace to find schema names of tables found above,
- execute a function for all tables with given name adding schema name as prefix.

Assuming you have defined function *do_something_with_this_table(tablename regclass)* earlier:

```
create function do_something_with_all_these_tables(tablename text)
returns void language plpgsql 
as $$
declare
    schemaname text;
begin
    for schemaname in
        select n.nspname
        from pg_class c
        join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
        where c.relkind = 'r' and c.relname = tablename
    loop
        execute format(
            'select do_something_with_this_table(''%s.%s'')',
            schemaname, tablename);
    end loop;
end $$;

select do_something_with_all_these_tables('given_table_name');
```

Read more:

- [about **plpgsql** language](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql.html)
- [about **format()** function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)